# How to properly expose APIs from Fargate tasks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecs

I deployed few microservices into Fargate. Each microservice will have around 30 API endpoints.

I have AWS ALB which will do the path based routing to the Fargate.

I created API Gateway APIs to externally expose the APIs. API Gateway integration method is HTTP and that points to the ALB endpoint.

Is this the proper way to setup the microservices? If not, please suggest the better approach.

And also, I want to automatically import the Swagger definition into API Gateway whenever there is a change in the Swagger definition. Swagger definition is exposed under /apidocs of each microservice. How do I automate the import of swagger definition into API gateway? Is there a commonly used approach?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind you'll need to update both API GW and ALB paths. To import new swagger definition you'll need some kind of triggered event to:

- Upload new swagger definition to S3.
- Create an API gateway [deployment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-deployments.html#create-deployment-using-cli).
- Perform the path edition in ALB target group(s). This one could be done by triggering a [CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/modify-target-group.html) or API call (or sdk).

If you use CloudFormation, you could trigger an UPDATE containing all these new changes too. If so, also keep an eye on those resources parameters that may or not require a resource replacing.

Hope it helps.